# How to implement firebase reCAPTCHA in react native without phone number sign in method?

Tags: react-native-firebase

I am creating a login / sign up page in react native and using firebase for authentication. I need a recaptcha modal like we have normally in app. How can I implement it in react native app using firebase recaptcha.

How can I get recaptcha modal in react native using firebase recaptcha